# Forcing HTTPS and avoid duplicate URLS using IIS7 URL Rewrite Module

Tags: asp.net, redirect, https, url-rewriting

I need to force every request to https://www.mysite.com (always with https and www)

The site is hosted in GoDaddy and I need to do it via IIS7 URL Rewrite Module.

I've been able to do the HTTPS redirect with the following code:

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />

                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite\.com$" />
                    </conditions>

                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mysite.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Test cases

- http://mysite.com -> https://www.mysite.com OK
- http://www.mysite.com -> https://www.mysite.com NOT WORKING

I guess the condition is not being satisfied when I enter www.mysite.com in the browser, so there's no redirect and the page serves as HTTP instead of HTTPS.

I think I just need to modify the condition pattern, but I have almost nothing regex knowledge and I need this asap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

emzero, I think the issue is that your condition only matches precisely `mysite.com`:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite\.com$" />
</conditions>
```

Note the pattern: `^mysite\.com$`. This says, in English, that the incoming URL must start with `mysite.com` and end with `mysite.com`, meaning `www.mysite.com` will *not* be matched.

Try this pattern instead, which allows for an option `www.`:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?mysite\.com$" />
</conditions>
```

Happy Programming!